# When might one use a scale-free neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

The structure of a feed-forward neural network is a directed acyclic network (DAG).  The neural network structures, such as in a MLP, we typically see in practice have a fixed structure, where the nodes in each layer are linked to each node in the next layer.

When might a general DAG structure outperform a MLP-style structure that is comparable in some sense (eg. an MLP with the same number of weights)?

This question is inspired by biology, where neural pathways, or cell signaling pathways, often have a feed-forward topology that is more like a scale-free network than a network of stacked layers.  I am certainly not the first to realize this, so I am wondering -- Where I might learn about the research and types of problems in this area?

Comment: not sure, but might be a better question for either the computer science or statistics sites

Comment: There is no specific name besides "not fully connected". There are dozens of architectures which have different connections, bypass ones etc. including highway networks, reservoir networks etc. simply take a look at neural net papers from NIPS conference, you will find dozens of such models

Answer (score 0):

One artificial example which you can imagine easily is when your input consists of two independent and highly complexed parts (e.g. concatenated inputs from two different sources) where you want to use this two kinds of information in order to obtain a better estimation of some output which depends on both sources. You may imagine then - that in a first few layers there is no need for connections between the parts of your network which are responsible for computations performed on different parts of your input because it will simply add some number of useless parameters what can harm your training.